# Swift function exits when instantiating object subclass

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have a very simple subclass of GMSMarker and in it I have added a couple of properties to make point markers more identifiable. In my subclass I have the following:

```
import UIKit

class PointMarker: GMSMarker {
    var layerID:String?
    var featureID:String?
}
```

In one class that uses the subclass, I have a function that renders map features.

```
func addRemoveMapPoint(featureDict:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, visible:Bool){

    if let properties = featureDict["properties"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        let marker:PointMarker = PointMarker()
        print(properties)

        // Code to render on the map ...
    }
}
```

This function can be called directly from an object instance or it can be called from an NSNotification. The weird behavior I am experiencing is that when called directly from code (not from a notification) all works as expected. However, when called from the NSNotification, the function exits on the line that creates an instance of `PointMarker`.

```
    let marker:PointMarker = PointMarker()
```

When code reaches this line, the function simply exits and no more code is executed. It behaves as if there is a break or return statement there. I receive no errors and the app does not crash. I have verified that the incoming parameter `featureDict` is identical whether called from an object or from a notification.

Can anyone offer an explanation as to why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: try to clean your project (build folder also).. I had some experiences with swift that it doesn't execute some lines .. this is not logic I know..but happened multiple times with me.